# passing dropdown's selected value from view to controller in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I have mvc3 web application.
In that i have used EF and populate two dropdownlists from database.

Now when i select values from those dropdownlists i need to show them inside webgrid
how can i do this?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Mapping</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
          @Html.Label("Pricing SecurityID")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ID,
         new SelectList(Model.ID, "Value", "Text"),
            "-- Select category --"
            )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ID)
        </div>

         <div class="editor-label">
          @Html.Label("CUSIP ID")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ddlId,
         new SelectList(Model.ddlId, "Value", "Text"),
            "-- Select category --"
            )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ddlId)
        </div>
         <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Mapping" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

when i clicked on `Mapping` button it will goes to new page called `Mapping.cshtml` and have to show webgrid with those two values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a ViewModel

```
public class YourClassViewModel
{

 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Securities{ get; set; }
 public int SelectedSecurityId { get; set; }

 public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CUSIPs{ get; set; }
 public int SelectedCUSIPId { get; set; }
```

}

and in my Get Action method, I will return this ViewModel to my strongly typed View

```
public ActionResult GetThat()
{
   YourClassViewModel objVM=new YourClassViewModel();
   objVm.Securities=GetAllSecurities() // Get all securities from your data layer 
   objVm.CUSIPs=GetAllCUSIPs() // Get all CUSIPsfrom your data layer    
   return View(objVm);  
}
```

And In my View Which is strongly typed,

```
@model YourClassViewModel     
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    Security :
     @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedSecurityId ,new SelectList(Model.Securities, "Value", "Text"),"Select one") <br/>

    CUSP:
     @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedCUSIPId ,new SelectList(Model.CUSIPs, "Value", "Text"),"Select one") <br/>

  <input type="submit" value="Save" />

}
```

and now in my HttpPost Action method,  I will accept this ViewModel as the parameter and i will have the Selected value there

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetThat(YourClassViewModel objVM)
{
   // You can access like objVM.SelectedSecurityId
   //Save or whatever you do please...   
}
```

Comment: Beautiful @Shyju. How can we use AutoMapper in GetThat action to map Domain model with View model?

Answer (score 0):

Post the form to `mapping actionresult`. in the actionresult mapping receive dropdown in parameters as `mapping(string ID, string ddID)`. Take these values to view using ViewData. 
A better approach will be to make a viewmodel for grid view and make your mapping view strongly typed and use value on grid as you required